# Why do I have the option in my wireless network of hpsetup?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

When I turned on my MacBook Pro today, (running OS X 10.8.2) I have a new option in my wireless network of "hpsetup" which I have never seen before. I thought out of interest I would try it & it allowed me to connect? My Wi-Fi toolbar icon changed to the same icon but with a small TV looking icon inside of it. 
Of course I had no internet coverage but I would love to know how it came about?
The only change I have made in the last 24 hours is adding software called MacKeeper to clean up my hardrive plus give me internet security. http://mackeeper.zeobit.com
I do do have any HP products in my house or in close proximity...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this has nothing to do with your setup and everything to do with a neighbours.  Someone near you has probably configured (or is in the process of configuring) a Wireless router which is currently named "HPSetup", and that devices is broadcasting [its SSID / Access Point name to you.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default wireless network set up by HP wireless printers. Sound's like someone in your area has been shopping.